# https with php curl - protocol not supported, but curl command line connects fine

Tags: php, curl, https

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595820/protocol-https-not-supported-or-disabled-in-libcurl)

I am trying to connect to a site via https using curl within php.

```
<?php
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp');
  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
?>
```

curl reuturns with

```
* Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

however using curl via command line works fine

```
  # curl https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp
```

I am running CentOS 5.8, WHM 11.32.2

```
# curl-config --features
SSL
IPv6
libz
IDN
NTLM


# curl-config --protocols
HTTP
HTTPS
FTP
FTPS
FILE
TELNET
LDAP
DICT
TFTP
NTLM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `curl` binary that you are running from the command line is one thing ; but it's pretty much independent from the `curl_*()` functions you are calling from PHP.

A feature being available from the curl-command line tool will not *(as you have noticed)* necessarily be available from PHP.

Here, you'll probably have to recompile PHP, to make sure it's compiled with SSL support.

Comment: Thank you! I have rebuilt the web server using easy-apache and enabled curl SSL. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

Enable  the extension **php_sockets**  in php.ini