# curl : (1) Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl [windows XP]

Tags: windows, ssl, curl, openssl, libcurl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595820/protocol-https-not-supported-or-disabled-in-libcurl)

I get this message when trying to execute Curl on Windows XP (32 bits).
Any idea how I can get it work?

Answer (score 0):

LibCURL can be compiled with or without openssl. You habe to link the open ssl binaries for the compilation using some cflags a dont know yet. Alittle google search will help you.

Greets