# Getting Error: "Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl" in Libcurl

Tags: curl, libcurl

I had a problem while making a URL call with curl.

First declare the curl.h file in curl version 7.40.0

```
#include "curl.h" // curl-7.40.0
```

In the function that calls curl...

```
CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
CURLcode res;
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.google.com");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TURE);
res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

When executing the above code, the following error occurs

- Rebuilt URL to: https://www.google.com/
- Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl
- Closing connection -1

Likewise, when I run it with the curl command in the Linux console, it runs normally. (curl version 7.19.7)

```
curl https://www.google.com
```

Can you tell me what's the problem?

thank you!

Comment: Does this solve your problem [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47978274/6446053)

Answer (score 3):

## Update your system

`sudo apt update`

## Install any build dependencies needed for curl

`sudo apt-get build-dep curl`

## Check versions

```
curl-config --version
# (maybe here you have 7.69-xxx)
curl --version
# 7.68.0
```

## Check path is correct

```
which curl
# /usr/local/bin/curl
whereis curl
# curl: /usr/bin/curl /usr/local/bin/curl /usr/share/man/man1/curl.1.gz
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
```

## Install LIB in order to get the same version

```
mkdir ~/curl
cd ~/curl
wget http://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.68.0.tar.bz2
tar -xvjf curl-7.68.0.tar.bz2 
cd curl-7.68.0/
./configure
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

## Check you have the same versions

```
curl-config --version
curl --version
```

Comment: it's a good guide. Thanks